# How do I find out more details about specific Yodlee account types?

Tags: yodlee

I have been looking at the Yodlee docs for the different account types (specifically the Investment account types: [documentation link](https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Data_Model/Yodlee_Account_Types#Investment_Account_Type)) and have two questions:

1. How do I find out more about some of the less-clear types like
   Simple (13), Corporate (29) or Administrator (55)?
2. There seem to be items missing from the enum - for example in our live data I have 28
   (individual) and 29 (corporate).  What are these?  Can they be added to the docs?

Comment: Why did someone downvote this?  The docs don't have the details. If you have a better source, please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matt- Here are the answers for your questions.

**Answer 1:**

**Simple:** This is a Savings Incentive Match Plan for Employees Individual Retirement Account, commonly known by the abbreviation "SIMPLE IRA". This is a type of tax-deferred employer-provided retirement plan.

**Corporate:** Corporate accounts are those that are registered in the corporation’s name. Accounts having the following keywords, Corporate, Partnership, Sole Proprietorship and Unincorporated Assn,  in the Account Name will be considered as Corporate Accounts. Going forward, this information will be captured as part of account classification rather than account type.

**Administrator:** This type of accounts used to be held by Fund administrators. The administrator accounts could have special privileges like consolidated reports. At present, Yodlee does not aggregate administrator accounts as the individual account level details are already getting aggregated.

**Answer 2:** Individual & Corporate are the account types and which generally being set at Yodlee end. As of now we are in process of deprecating these two account types(that's why not mentioned it over portal) and going forward this information would be captured as part of account classification rather than account type.

Comment: Thank you.  So, curiously, what will the accountType be when accountClassification is Corporate or Individual?  I see the property only on BankData (and CardData, but not Investment Data). Also, are there plans to add this to InvestmentData or does it not apply?

Comment: @MattHagopian - As mentioned we are still in process of considering/deciding the new account types which will take place once we will move the Corporate & Individual at account classification level. And yes InvestmentData has also been considered to have this property. But as of now I can't provide you a specific timeline about the same.